# Implementations of Tutte polynomial [reference request, of a kind]

Tags: graph-theory, tutte-polynomial

This question is not a 100% fit for MO, but it is a serious question that can be viewed as a sort of reference request, and I think fits here more than elsewhere.

I have been asked to write a chapter describing computational resources for the practical computation of the Tutte polynomial. To keep the scope reasonable, I have decided to look at, evaluate and describe programs that are

1. widely and reasonably easily available (should be able to download, compile and install today)
2. general purpose (no particular restrictions to subclasses of graphs), and
3. (ideally) described in a widely available publication, tech report, arxiv paper etc.

Three programs so far meet these criteria - my own program developed with Haggard/Pearce, a program based on tree decompositions by the statistical physicists Bedini/Jacobsen and a third by Bjorklund et. al.  The first has its own webpage, while the latter two are on GitHub hence meeting the "availability" criterion.

In addition, there are implementations in Sage and Maple and also a couple of other programs that can be downloaded from the web, but which (AFAIK) do not have papers describing them.

I know that there are lots of other people who have written their own programs for their own personal use, but have no intention of distributing them.

However I do not wish to offend anyone by omitting their program due to my lack of knowledge, and I want the chapter to give an accurate overview of the available resources.

Thus, finally, my question:

*Are there other widely available, general purpose, implemented algorithms for computing the Tutte polynomial (partition function of the $q$-state Potts model) for an input graph with no particular structural constraints?*

Comment: Just as a note, the one in Sage is actually an implementation of the algorithm described in your paper.

Comment: There are two implementations in **sage**: a naive one going through the matroid of a graph, and a more efficient and direct one. And the code is of course freely available and fully documented.